# HashMap function 'put' not working properly - Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am reading through a CSV and saving the data to objects (an object is created for each row). The rows in the CSV are grouped by the first element (group number) - somewhere between 2-10ish rows share a group number. There are ~180 groups in the data set. To handle this data more easily, I store the data into HashMaps, where the key is the group number, and the value tied to the key is an ArrayList of the data objects.

As I iterate through the CSV's rows, I add objects to the HashMap, using the row's group number to tell where to put the new data object. If the object has a group number which has not been entered into the CSV yet, it creates a new key (its group number) and an ArrayList of data objects, containing just itself.

If the row's group number IS a key in the HashMap, it gets the ArrayList tied to the group number, adds the new data object to it, and uses the put function to re-add the new entry, with the updated ArrayList (now with one more data entry tied to the shared group number).

Code example:

```
  ArrayList<CSVData> csvListNew = new ArrayList<CSVData>();
  HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<CSVData>> CSVDataMapNew = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<CSVData>>();
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !(line.contains(",,,,,,,,,"))) 
{
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] csvDataNew = line.split(",");
            String currentGroup = csvDataNew[GroupIndex];
            try {
                currentGroupNumber = Integer.parseInt(currentGroup.replace("group", "").replace(" ", ""));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                currentGroupNumber = previousGroupNumber;
            }
            String path = csvDataNew[PathIndex];
            startLine = Integer.parseInt(csvDataNew[StartLineIndex]);
            endLine = Integer.parseInt(csvDataNew[EndLineIndex]);

            CSVData data = new CSVData(currentGroupNumber, path, startLine, endLine);

            if (CSVDataMapNew.containsKey(currentGroupNumber)) { //if it does contain the current key, add the current object to the ArrayList tied to it.
                csvListNew = CSVDataMapNew.get(currentGroupNumber);
                csvListNew.add(clone);
                CSVDataMapNew.put(currentGroupNumber, csvListNew);
            } else { //if it doesnt contain the current key, make new entry
                csvListNew.add(clone);
                CSVDataMapNew.put(currentGroupNumber, csvListNew);
                System.out.println(CSVDataMapNew.size());
                System.out.println(CSVDataMapNew.get(currentGroupNumber).size());
            }
            csvListNew.clear(); //to make sure no excess objects are entered into the map.
            previousGroupNumber = currentGroupNumber;
        }
```

There are appropriate try-catches, etc. and the CSVDataTable is declared in its own class, being referenced statically.

The issue is, when I add in print statements at each step, its like each ArrayList within the HashMap gets erased at the end of every loop. So once the CSV is finished being iterated through, it has each key value, but the ArrayLists tied to each key are all empty. (Evidenced by looping through the HashMap afterwards).

How can I resolve this, so when I enter a value into the ArrayList and re 'put' the key and updated ArrayList into the Map, it keeps its data?

Comment: Change `csvListNew.clear();` to `csvListNew = new ArrayList<CSVData>();`. The way you have it now, you're putting the same list in the map each time. And you're clearing it at the end of your loop each time.

Comment: Your code is difficult to read. Why did you capitalize the one object `CSVDataMapNew`? It makes it look like you are working w/a static class.

Comment: "The issue is, when I add in print statements at each step, its like each ArrayList within the HashMap gets erased at the end of every loop." - well yes, you're calling `clear()` on the list whose reference you've just put in the map...

Comment: @rabbitguy I added in the declaration of CSVDataMapNew into the question so everything necessary to understand my code was there. It actually is a static object in another class but it was just so people answering my question could see all relevant bits of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always put the same `ArrayList` instance as value in your `HashMap`. That's the `ArrayList` instance created before the loop and referenced by the `csvListNew` variable.

This means that when you call `csvListNew.clear()`, you clear all the `ArrayList`s of your `HashMap`.

This can be fixed by creating a new `ArrayList` each time you want to put a new entry in your `HashMap`:

```
        if (CSVDataMapNew.containsKey(currentGroupNumber)) {
            csvListNew = CSVDataMapNew.get(currentGroupNumber);
            csvListNew.add(clone);
        } else {
            csvListNew = new ArrayList<>(); // that's the main required fix
            csvListNew.add(clone);
            CSVDataMapNew.put(currentGroupNumber, csvListNew);
            System.out.println(CSVDataMapNew.size());
            System.out.println(CSVDataMapNew.get(currentGroupNumber).size());
        }
```

In addition, remove the `csvListNew.clear()` call.

Answer (score 2):

> So once the CSV is finished being iterated through, it has each key
>   value, but the ArrayLists tied to each key are all empty. (

This

```
  ArrayList<CSVData> csvListNew = new ArrayList<CSVData>();
```

should be invoked and associated to each key of your map.
But you use a single instance of the `ArrayList` as value for every key of your map.

And at the end of your method, you do :

```
 csvListNew.clear();
```

So all your values of your map are an empty `ArrayList` as all refers to the same  `ArrayList`.

To solve your problem, if the key doesn't exist in the map you should create a new ArrayList and associate it to this key :

```
  ArrayList<CSVData> csvListNew = CSVDataMapNew.get(currentGroupNumber);

  if (csvListNew == null) 
     csvListNew = new ArrayList<CSVData>();
     CSVDataMapNew.put(csvListNew);
  }
```

Then reuse the `csvListNew` variable to add the element in:

```
 csvListNew.add(clone);
```

It simplifies your actual code that has undesirable duplication.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a list from a hashMap you get a reference to the list. Everything you do with this list afterwards will affect the list that is in the map. This means two things:

- You don't have to put the List back into the map after you added something to it
- You have to create a new List for every Map entry. You currently don't do that.

This should fix it (also some adjusted code style):

```
    Map<Integer,List<CSVData>> CSVDataMapNew = new HashMap<>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !(line.contains(",,,,,,,,,")))
    {
        System.out.println(line);
        String[] csvDataNew = line.split(",");
        String currentGroup = csvDataNew[GroupIndex];
        try {
            currentGroupNumber = Integer.parseInt(currentGroup.replace("group", "").replace(" ", ""));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            currentGroupNumber = previousGroupNumber;
        }
        String path = csvDataNew[PathIndex];
        startLine = Integer.parseInt(csvDataNew[StartLineIndex]);
        endLine = Integer.parseInt(csvDataNew[EndLineIndex]);

        CSVData data = new CSVData(currentGroupNumber, path, startLine, endLine);

        if (CSVDataMapNew.containsKey(currentGroupNumber)) { 
            CSVDataMapNew.get(currentGroupNumber).add(clone);
        } else { 
            ArrayList<CSVData> csvListNew = new ArrayList<CSVData>();
            CSVDataMapNew.put(currentGroupNumber, csvListNew);
            csvListNew.add(clone);
        }
        previousGroupNumber = currentGroupNumber;
    }
```